# Filtering out unknown disciminators with Hibernate, for backward compatibility

Tags: hibernate, jpa, discriminator

I have a an **Hibernate** application mapping a hierarchy of classes to a single table with usage of **discriminator** strategy. In **v1.0** it looks like that :

- AbstractType

  - SubType1 (v1.0) discr=**subtype1**

Then, I load a new version **v2.0** of my application, that handles a new subtype **SubType2**, with a new discriminator :

- AbstractType

  - SubType1 (v1.0) discr=**subtype1**
  - SubType2 (v2.0) discr=**subtype2**

After some new data have been written, I would like to still be able to **fallback** my code to **v1.0**, in case of problem.

For that purpose, I need **v1.0** to filter out / ignore table rows with discriminator **subtype2**.

How can I achieve that in a generic way, either with **JPA API** or **Hibernate** implementation ? Can I "hook" to Hibernate internals with a **custom Dialect** ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use hibernate's filters. 
Just in case if you have decided to rollback on version 1. You can define a row level filter in hibernate cfg file.
E.g. where type = :v1